# Phonegap deviceready not working when page visited second time

Tags: ios, google-maps, cordova

i am trying to create a map with phonegap + google maps for ios. It works fine the first time but if I navigate to another page and then I return again to my maps page, nothing seems to happen, seems like deviceready is not fired. Any idea?

```
<script src="phonegap.js"></script>
<script src="maparestaurante.js"></script>
<link href="styles/retina.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" />



</head>

<body onload="onLoad()">
```

and the javascript:

```
function onLoad() {
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onLoad2, true);
}
function onLoad2() {
if (navigator.geolocation) {
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
} else {
error('not supported');
}
}
```

As I said, this works fine the first time, but if maps section visited again, it will never work, when testing it in the browser everyting worked fine

thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

deviceReady will be fired only once. when the app is initialized. When you want to fire the load function when  the page is visited again, you need to call the function again in the "page view " (which ever event supported by your SPA framework)event.